# Linking error with GLFW using mingw-w64

Tags: c, batch-file, glfw, mingw-w64

I know this answer has been asked before, but I haven't been able to find a solution. I'm using Emacs and a batch file to run gcc, but I keep getting undefined reference errors back from the compiler.

Here is my code:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

void
wf_init(const char* title)
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
      // Error message
    }

    puts("Hello");
}

void
wf_update(void)
{

}

void
wf_quit(void)
{
    glfwTerminate();
}

int main()
{
    wf_init("HELLO");
```

`}

And here is my batch file code:

```
@echo off
cls
cd C:/Users/surafel911/Documents/Coding/Projects/Engines/Test/
@echo on
gcc -o bin/debug/main code/main.c code/src/*.c -g -Werror -std=c11 ^
-
IC:/Users/surafel911/Documents/Coding/Projects/Engines/Test/external/include 
^
-LC:/Users/surafel911/Documents/Coding/Projects/Engines/Test/external/lib ^
-lmingw32 -lopengl32 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -lglfw3
@echo off
cd C:/Users/surafel911/Documents/Coding/Projects/Engines/Test/build/
```

Comment: Post your linking errors (the output of your batch script).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently all I needed to do was rearrange the libraries I passed into gcc, so putting in

```
-lmingw32 -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32
```

Made everything work. I read somewhere that the order that you pass in your libraries is important, so this must be an example of that.